# How to Display Data from Table relationship base on ID come from first table LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 table, table Courses, table Sections, and table Syllabuses. Where table courses relation to table Sections and table Sections relation to table Syllabuses. To make clear below my table look like:

#Table Courses:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->default('1');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('status')->default('publish');
            $table->text('content')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Table Sections:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and the last table Syllabuses:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('syllabuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('section_id');
            $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('sections')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('content')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and now I'm stuck to display data from table syllabuses base on Sections's ID, where the sections display base on Courses's ID, because I don't know how to get the ID from each row which related to Secations's ID to put in `Syllabus::where('section_id',???)->get();`. Anyone who can help me much much appreciate. Hope u understand what I mean.

Below the image you can see, there I have put some note to make u understand. The problem in the green box one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcEPr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define relations in your models first.
I assume your models are: Course, Section and Syllabus

```
// Model Course
public function sections()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Section::class);
}

// Model Section
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}

public function syllabuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Syllabus::class);
}

// Model Syllabus
public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
}
```

Now in your controller you can get your designated course by

```
// Controller Course

public function show($id)
{
    $course = Course::with('sections', 'sections.syllabuses')->where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

In this query you have a model from "Course" table, related models from "Sections" table and all the related models from "Syllabuses" table. If you are using laravel's blade then you can simply access them by:

```
// course
{!! $course->your_attribute !!}

// to access sections
@foreach($course->sections as $section)

@endforeach

// to access syllabuses
@foreach($course->sections as $section)
     @foreach($section->syllabuses as $syllabus)
          // Here you will have syllabuses for individual sections
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Hi Hossain, as you assume all is alright, and I have updated my code model and blade above, please look. And I have to do as you say and it's work but work not as I want. from your code all Syllabuses data display but not based on SECTIONS' ID. Please help me, I'm stuck for almost 4 hours here and I can't continue if this is not solved ;).

Comment: I'm just confused about how to display all that syllabuses data based on Sections ID. Let's say to displaying course and section it's okay 'cause I can get the ID from `$request->route('course')`. but what about Syllabuses.

Comment: Thank u so much bro, it's worked right now. What I have done as u tell me, I just put this code `@foreach($course->sections as $section)
     @foreach($section->syllabuses as $syllabus)
          // Here you will have syllabuses for individual sections
     @endforeach
@endforeach`. What make before didn't work 'cause I put this code `@foreach($course->sections as $section)` double in my blade. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study laravel relationships in your case you have belongsTo relation.

In your Syllabus model add.

```
public function section(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Section::class, 'section_id');
}
```

Then you can use this will get all Syllabuses with related to there sections.

```
Syllabus::with('section')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, bro, I'm still fighting bro.